# How to get a 64-bit integer without using gmpy?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to pass a 64-bit integer into a function from a DLL, but the native python int types are 12 bytes (`sys.getsizeof(1)` returns 12) and I get the error "ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (4 bytes in excess)". Is there a way I can initialize an 8-byte integer or convert to one?

I've tried using ctypes to pass in the parameter as various different ctype integers, but I couldn't get this to work:
`mydll.dllfn(c_int(1))`, `mydll.dllfn(c_int64(1))`, `mydll.dllfn(c_long(1))`, etc.

I would like to avoid gmpy since the platform I am running on is not currently being maintained or supported by gmpy.

Comment: could you update your question to include the code are you using to call the function?  [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_int64) has `int64`, `long long` and `uint64` types…

Comment: *native python int types are 12 bytes*  ...huh?

Comment: Python the language has no notion of X-bit integers for any X; it only supports arbitrary precision integers. If you need to pass such an integer as an 8-byte value, you need to pack it accordingly; what are you doing *now* that you got a 12-byte value?

Answer (score 2):

Using stdlib [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html):

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.c_int64(1)
c_long(1)
```

It's usually an alias for [`c_longlong`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_longlong), which represents the C signed long long datatype.

```
>>> ctypes.c_int64 is ctypes.c_longlong
True
```

Note that these types have no overflow checking!

```
>>> ctypes.c_int64(2**63-1)
c_long(9223372036854775807)
>>> ctypes.c_int64(2**63)
c_long(-9223372036854775808)
```

There's `ctypes.c_uint64` / `ctypes.c_ulonglong` if you wanted unsigned.

Depending on how the interfaces looks, you may also be interested in [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack):

```
>>> struct.pack('q', 2**63-1)
'\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x7f'
```

The 'q' refers to the 8 byte integer type ('Q' is unsigned). Other format characters are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters). Byte order, size, and alignment options are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).